# Reddit api/friend JSON request from Android

Tags: android, json, api, reddit

I am trying to use `api/friend` to add a friend by posting JSON request from an Android mobile.

In my code, post request returns html code and fails to add the friend.
Edit:Change to use UrlEncodedFormEntity  for HttpPost.

```
List<NameValuePair> qparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(Common.KEY_NAME, name));
    qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(Common.KEY_CONTAINER, "t2_"
            + container));
    qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(Common.KEY_TYPE, "friend"));
    qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(Common.KEY_USER, uh));
    try {
        return new UrlEncodedFormEntity(qparams);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: This code doesn't perform an http request. It just creates a URI.

Comment: Yes. this just create URI to be used for HttpClient to Send Post Request.

Comment: You probably need to do a POST request. This looks like you're doing a GET request instead.